# Django-celery-beat is scheduling interval tasks continuously

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I recently followed this tutorial:
https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/celery-redis-django/

in order to configure django-celery-beat. Everything works fine if I start the beat worker like this:

```
celery -A proj beat -l info
```

however, if I get the beat scheduler to use the django DB, as follows:

```
celery -A proj beat -l info -S django
```

it starts to stream out tasks to the worker continuously (and not based on the specified interval.

This seems to only happen for interval tasks, and not for crontab tasks...

Further info:
I'm using:

```
Django==1.11.5
celery==4.1.0
django-celery-beat==1.1.0
django-celery-results=1.0.1
```

What could be the issue?

**update**

I am scheduling the interval tasks directly into the DB through the django admin interface. I've actually noticed that all scheduled intervals are set to execute at a scheduled time of 1 minute less than specified...

For e.g.,

- Interval time: 2 mins - executed every 1 minute
- Interval time: 65 seconds - executed every 5 seconds
- Interval time: 60 seconds or less - executed continuously....

So the scheduled continuously problem seems to originate with this...

Comment: Can you also add how are you creating the interval tasks?

Comment: Just updated the question to include how I'm scheduling and a potential bug